# Android XML properties: match_parent + 50pixels

Tags: android, webview, web

I need to display a website in my app, but **I don't want to display its footer to my users**, which should be around 50pixels, I have no control over footer, and its my website(no offence).

I can overlap a button on it, but is there a way to show **a webview matching parent plus an extra 50pixels which should be out of display.**

The web content will change time to time.

Thanks in advance for your help and support.

Comment: can you put xml here

Comment: Why don't you parse the website content and remove the footer programatically ?

Comment: #Nishith, I am not that good.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah I just got an idea, didnt work on it, wanted to know any workaround from experienced players.  Thank You

Comment: It is not possible. You need to change your layout hierarchy to extend 50 pixel more than ex parent view.

Comment: You can go for JSOUP library. It reads and then parses a webpage content. From the parsed content you just need to remove the footer content.

Comment: @zilk any sample ?

Comment: @Nishith just to remove a footer line, parsing each and every time, too hectic.

Comment: I used to do the same thing in html using iframes, it was too simple.

Comment: It depends on your requirement. Its a bit comliplicated, but most efficient. However, you can take it as the last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="XXX" />
```